# Week View Control for Cocoa (Apple Mac OS X Dev)

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, xcode, calendar

does anyone know if there is a control for Cocoa that has the same abilities like the iCal Week View? Which means a spreadsheet like view for the whole week with Appointments to render in their timeframe.

I searched through Google for some time now and didn't find anything.

Thx in Advance

Steve

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://code.google.com/p/csweekview/

UPDATE: Found the same thing on GitHub, not sure which one is more recent

http://github.com/davehirsch/CSWeekView

Comment: I updated my post above with a link to a copy of the source I found on GitHub too. Not sure which one is more recent, the Google Code hosted one or the one on GitHub, but they both have the same author.

Comment: Thx for this hint - not exactly what I'm looking for but very close.

Is there a week view with vertical alignment of appointments out there?

Comment: I don't think there is, but I'm sure that modifying this to display vertically shouldn't take too long.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is a custom view. You'll have to roll your own or find a third-party open source alternative, I'm afraid.